# "Alphabet of Programminglanguage X" means really the Characters or Words?

Tags: programming-languages

In the Dragonbook's exercise 3.3.1 the student should

> Consult the language reference manuals
>   to determine (i) the set of characters
>   that form the input alphabet
>   (excluding those that may only appear
>   in character strings or comments [...]
>   for each of the following languages:
>   [...].

It makes no real sense to me to describe really all the characters like `a`, `b`, `/` for a language, even if it is an exercise for compilers. Isn't the alphabet of a programming language the set of possible words, like `{id, int, float, string, if, for, ... }`?

And if you consider it really beeing "characters" in the basic idea of the word, is `??/` in C one or three charaters (or both)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alphabet of a language is the set of characters not the words.

> Isn't the alphabet of a programming
>   language the set of possible words,
>   like {id, int, float, string, if, for,
>   ... }?

No, the alphabet is the set of characters that are used to form words. When an language is specified, the alphabet must be given otherwise you cannot distinguish a valid token from an invalid token.

**Update**

You are confusing the term "word" with "token". A word is not some part of a language or program. A word is finite string of characters from the alphabet. It has nothing to do with a language construct like "int" or "while". For example, each C program is a word because it is a finite string of characters from the alphabet. The set of all of these programs (words) forms the C programming language. Tokens like "void" or "int" are entirely a different thing.

To recap, you start by defining the some set of characters you want to use. This is called the alphabet. Finite strings of these characters form words. A language is some subset of all possible words. To define a language, you define which words belong to the language. For example, with a regular expression or a context-free grammar.

Wikipedia has a good page on formal languages.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language

Comment: With your answer and the book I think I get it. You just look at the language like a Lexer would do. For him there are no words, only a string of characters who he might accept and form to words or not.

Comment: @ erikb, No, that is not quite right either. A language is some subset of all possible finite strings over the alphabet. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes from theory defining *alphabet* as the set of symbols from which the strings in a language are formed. Note that the grammars for programming languages use *tokens* and not characters as *terminal symbols*.

Traditionally, from the perspective of language theory, programming languages involve two language definitions: 1) The one that has characters as the alphabet and tokens as the valid strings. 2) The one that has tokens as the alphabet and programs as the valid strings. That's why programming languages are usually specified in two parts, a lexical, and a syntactical analyzer.

It is not strictly necessary to have the two definitions to parse a programming language. A single grammar can be used to specify a programming language using characters as the input alphabet. It's just that the characters-to-token parts has been easier to specify with regular expressions, and the tokens-to-program part with grammars.

Modern compiler-compilers like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) use grammar-specification languages that incorporate the expressive convenience of regular expressions, so a character-to-program definition can be done with a single grammar. Still, separating the *lexical* from the *syntactical* remains the most convenient way to parse a programming language, even with such tools.

Last minute example: imagine that the grammar productions for an if-then-else-end had to deal at the character-level with:

- Whitespace.
- Keywords within programming language strings: "Then, the end."
- Variable names that contain keywords: 'tiff',
- ...

It can be done, but it would be extremely complicated.